# Determining when focus occurs outside an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to see if the following is possible:

- Determining if focus occurs outside an element without the use of document level global selectors such as `$(document)`, `$(body)`, `$(window)` and the like due to performance reasons.
- If it is not possible to achieve without global selectors, explain yourself with a provable reason. It is important that I understand why this is not doable with today's latest techniques.
- **Bonus Round**: Determining the most efficient (computation time wise) selector(s)/event handler(s)/plugin(s) for the task.

**[My implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/AGE/d5fa5o8q/)** consists of a very simple HTML navigation bar as seen in the snippet below. I do native keyboard navigation between each `<a>` tag. The first list element is the title, containing an anchor that is visible, the second element

```
<ul class="test">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Title</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Some link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Some link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Some link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Some link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The goal of this navigation bar is simple:

1. Native keyboard tab or shift+tab to go from anchor to anchor.
2. Show the drop down menu when focusing on the inner anchor elements.
3. Hide the drop down menu when not focusing on any inner anchor elements.

I have 1 and 2 down, but 3 is tricky because of the requirements listed above. I know this can be very easily be done using a global selector, but this challenge is about figuring out and understanding if it can be done otherwise.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    dropdownMenu = $(".test > ul");
    dropdownMenu.hide();

    $(".test").focusin(function() {
        if (dropdownMenu.is(":hidden")) {
          dropdownMenu.show();
        }
    });
    // Some selector for some event here to handle the focus/clicks outside the $(".test") element
});
```

**Important**: I consider `event.stopPropagation();`, as explained in [CSS Tricks - The Dangers of Stopping Event Propagation](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/) to be a dangerous technique for the scope of this question, however if using said technique results in the *most efficient approach* then I will welcome it.

Comment: Maybe this is too simple an approach, but wouldn't the solution be doing certain checks based on `blur` events? Perhaps checking if any outer elements are still focused (or have an inner element that is), rather than having to check the whole document?

Comment: @GregL that is where my dilemma lies, what is the selector I should be looking for `blur` if not a global one? I tried `$(document.activeElement)` which listens to the current active element correctly, but under which event handler? When using `blur` it will mess up the show/hide functions currently existing in the snippet. Give it a try

Comment: A side comment on functionality: depending on how deep the list is, having to tab through each child before getting on to the next sibling might be very annoying. Instead, I would have thought it would be better to have some other key to expand the node, so you can jump between siblings only with Tab/Shift-Tab.

Comment: @GregL thankfully on the live implementation the navigation has been optimized, this is a mere snippet to demonstrate the challenge I am currently facing. Regarding doing what I need to do for this problem, I can easily achieve it using `$(document).click` but I am here on (hopefully not) a crusade of sorts. I appreciate the concern however :-)

Comment: I'm not clear on why `$(".test").focusout` doesn't meet your criteria here - can you clarify?

Comment: @nrabinowitz uncomment the snippet in the jsFiddle (easier to see than to explain). So what you will see that, yes it does attempt to do what I intend it to do, but it also disrupts `$(.test)` from being visible. In my tests with `focusout` I noticed: `focusin` and `focusout` occur one after the other, meaning the `focusout` event will occur but it does not achieve the desired functionality. Perhaps I am using it improperly? Well that is why I am here :-)

Comment: Either this works as intended in Chrome, or I'm missing some aspect of your intent. I see that when I tab through all the entries and then tab out the dropdown menu disappears but the "Title" element remains visible.

Comment: @nrabinowitz that is amazing to me. I am using Chrome, I am looking into the provided jsFiddle, however what you describe is not working for me.  This is what I notice: I tab into the title element, then I press tab which should naturally take me to the first child anchor element, at that same instant the list disappears leaving the title visible, which is the expected incorrect behavior. Care to explain yourself a little better?

Comment: I don't have the problem you report - when I am focused on "Title" and press tab I tab correctly to the first child. But I believe you that the issue exists for some browsers and some versions of Chrome.

Comment: @nrabinowitz The problem the OP is talking about only happens if you uncomment the `focusout` handler in the fiddle.

Comment: Yes, I did that. It works as expected for me. Some versions of Chrome presumably handle this differently.

Comment: @nrabinowitz I **really** wish I could reproduce it, can you reproduce it GregL?

Comment: @AGE It works for me in Chrome as well (when I uncomment those lines). Chrome v46.0.2490.86 Linux.

Comment: @JoshCrozier my version is Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit) not sure if that matters

Comment: When I uncomment those lines in Chrome, I tab once and it opens the submenu, I tab again and the submenu disappears. This is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option here, without global selectors, is to delay the close action briefly:

```
  var isVisible = false;

  $(".test").focusin(function() {
    if (dropdownMenu.is(":hidden")) {
      dropdownMenu.show();
    }
    isFocused = true;
  });

  $(".test").focusout(function() {
    isFocused = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!isFocused && dropdownMenu.is(":visible")) {
        dropdownMenu.hide();
      }
    }, 100);
  });
```

This is a little fiddly, but protects you from errant closes while tabbing. See https://jsfiddle.net/d5fa5o8q/4/

Comment: I like it, I noticed that `focusout` really got in the way of what happens between focus events, never had occurred to me I should have used a timeout function, very nice! I will try this on my live site tomorrow and keep you posted. How do you think your answer performs against Bill's? I mean on the comments, he added a jsFiddle example thats quite neat. I am also interested in the best performance wise approach (as little as it may be)

Comment: this worked great in my live implementation, I am glad for you and everyone else who put in the effort to figuring out a (slightly?) better approach than using a more global selector such as `$(document)`. Kudos!

Comment: If you're actually concerned about perf, I'm betting the `is(":hidden")` and `is(":shown")` checks are actually the most expensive part here - just call `show` and `hide`, and it'll be a no-op in the false case. But I think perf should not be a big concern in either case, unless you have a perf-intensive application (e.g. animations occurring during this action), and that argues for simpler code over high performance.

Comment: That's interesting I didn't expect the `is()` to be more expensive than the `hide()` or `show()`. By the way I also don't think the performance impact is a big deal, however on my end my hand is being forced into it, which is not a bad thing at all plus it makes it a more compelling SO question.

Comment: `is` isn't necessarily expensive, but it has to evaluate the selector against the element, and `:visible` and `:hidden` are expensive selectors (non-native).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I'm following the question 100% but I think I got you.

You can use `event.target` with `closest` using the `focusin` event.

```
$(document).on('focusin', function (event) {
  var $target = $(event.target);
  if (!$target.closest('.bar').length) {
    console.log('You focused outside of .bar!');
  }
});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/qk14r7c7/2/

Comment: I like the idea, however my challenge is avoiding the use of global selectors such as `$(document)`, because of performance reasons. I know this is not as simple without the use of a global selector, which is why I am also interested in knowing whether or not it can be done without a global selector

Comment: You can use the code with any other selector and it'll still work. I'm not sure how this would cause performance issues though.

Comment: I believe you, I am also (secretly) out to disprove a co-worker/boss who think that using a global selector will cause such large performance issues. But besides that, this is a worth while question to ask because, if it is possible then it is a much better option in terms of performance.

Comment: the global selector `$(document)` will not cause you any performance issues if you cache it after the first call.

Comment: Back to your comment regarding *use the code with any other selector and it'll still work*, which selector do you mean I should use to check for focus outside `$(.test)`?

Comment: @Jason how can you cache it?

Comment: `let x = $(document);` now it's cached every time you call `x`

Comment: @Jason that's right (duh moment), in that case I can use `x` instead of `$(document)` to search and listen on the elements every time without causing any variation in performance?

Comment: That's not the perf issue here though - the perf issue is that *every* `focusin` event on the page will go through this handler, and this handler does a potentially expensive DOM lookup every time to see if we're on the relevant element. Perf issues are definitely possible, though it may not matter if the rest of your page isn't perf-intensive.

Comment: @nrabinowitz the argument I have on my end is that it may be perf intensive (where are the facts though, who knows I would rather assume the following: *who cares get it done*). Therefore, if caching `$(document)` and using an event handler will always cause an expensive lookup, then we are back on square one :-(

Comment: I'm definitely not following you at all.

Comment: @BillCriswell is there a way of doing what you just did, without using `$(document)` but another selector instead, which is not: `$(window)` or anything global like that? This is because of possible expensive DOM lookup on every single time `focusin` is called. I am simply trying to understand **is that even possible** and if so, **how can it be done?**

Comment: You can use any selector you want. It seems like you're prematurely optimising here. The only way I can see you running into performance issues is if you're focusing 1000 times a second and the input is nested like 500 elements deep inside a possible `.bar`. Here it is using just `input` as the selector, though: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/qk14r7c7/3/

Comment: @BillCriswell this is very close to the actual implementation on the live site that I have, I think your approach really clears up that I need to make sure I do this on the correct selector for my case. As far as the example snippet goes however, you got it! Please edit your original answer with the above comment and jsFiddle.

Comment: @BillCriswell I will test tomorrow on my live site and update if I have any lingering issues.